# How to convert from native php to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following db and php. I am trying to make a unordered list of category menu.
The original php is working by itself.
I am trying to convert this to MVC in codeigniter and the following is what I got so far and not working.
If someone can point out what I am doing wrong, I will appreciate it.

Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `longdesc` text NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
-- 

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `shortdesc`, `longdesc`, `status`, `parentid`) VALUES (1, 'shoes', 'Shoes for boys and girls.', '', 'active', 7);
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `shortdesc`, `longdesc`, `status`, `parentid`) VALUES (2, 'shirts', 'Shirts and blouses!', '', 'active', 7);
...
...
```

menu.php (original php and working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>View Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Menu</h3>
<?php 
function make_list ($parent) {

    global $data;
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($parent as $task_id => $todo) {

        echo "<li>$todo";

        if (isset($data[$task_id])) { 

            make_list($data[$task_id]);
        }

        echo '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';

} 

$dbc = @mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root1', 'root', 'ci_day6') OR die ('<p>Could not connect to the database!</p></body></html>');

$q = 'SELECT id, parentid, name FROM categories ORDER BY parentid ASC'; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

$data = array();

while (list($id, $parentid, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    $data[$parentid][$id] =  $name;

}

make_list($data[0]);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This php output the following html

```
Menu

    * clothes
          o shoes
          o shirts
          o pants
          o dresses
    * fun
          o toys
          o games
```

My MVC so far and not working.

cat_menu_model.php(model)

```
<?php

class Cat_menu_model extends Model
{
         function Cat_menu_model()
        {
            parent::Model();

        }

        function get_categories_nav()
        {

            $data = array();
            $this->db->select('id,name,parentid');
            $this->db->where('status', 'active');
            $this->db->orderby('parentid','asc');
            $this->db->orderby('name','asc');

            $Q = $this->db->get('categories');
        if ($Q -> num_rows() > 0){
          foreach ($Q -> result_array() as $row){
          $data[$row['parentid']][$row['id']] = $row['name'];
          }
          }

           $Q->free_result(); 
           return $data; 

        }
}
```

cat_menu.php (controller)

```
<?php

class Cat_menu extends Controller
{

    function Cat_menu()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }
    function make_menu($parent)
    {
        $this->load->model('cat_menu_model');

        $data['navlist'] = $this->cat_menu_model->get_categories_nav();
            $this -> load ->view('menu');
    }
}
```

menu.php(view)

```
<?php
if (count($navlist))
{
  $this->make_menu($data[0]);
  echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($parent as $id => $catname) {

        echo "<li>$catname";

        if (isset($data[$id])) { 

        make_menu($data[$id]);

        }

        echo '</li>';

    } 
 echo '</ol>';
}
?>
```

It shows an error messages.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Cat_menu::make_menu()

Filename: controllers/cat_menu.php

Line Number: 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the PHP error message above, it's saying that you've told the method Cat_menu::make_menu() to accept an argument. In this case the function **make_menu($parent)** in the **Cat_menu** controller.

If this function does not require any input -- doesn't look like $parent is used -- then just remove the $parent argument from make_menu.

Alternatively, set a default value if you would like the function to accept no arguments. See below:

*cat_menu.php (Controller)*

```
<?php

class Cat_menu extends Controller
{

    function Cat_menu()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function make_menu($parent = FALSE) //Is this $parent argument needed?
    {
        $this->load->model('cat_menu_model');

        $data['navlist'] = $this->cat_menu_model->get_categories_nav();

        //If you want to parse data to a view you need to state it
        $this->load->view('menu', $data);
    }
}
```

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, this should now work. Please see the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) for reference from now on. Specifically the [views documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) on parsing values across.

---

**OP* has since responded in the comments below, this is my response.**

**OP = Original Poster*

When running print_r($navlist) in the view. The OP gets the following output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [7] => clothes 
        [8] => fun 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [3] => pants 
        [2] => shirts 
        [1] => shoes 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [6] => games 
        [5] => toys 
    )
)
```

However, it is worth noting that the OP's CI model ActiveRecord query is significantly different than the original -- non MVC -- query:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    parentid, 
    name 
FROM 
    categories 
ORDER BY 
    parentid ASC
```

vs.

```
$this->db->select('id,name,parentid');
$this->db->where('status', 'active');
$this->db->orderby('parentid','asc');
$this->db->orderby('name','asc');
$Q = $this->db->get('categories');
```

The CI model query is different than the original SQL to begin with. When converted into SQL it would produce the following:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    name,
    parentid
FROM
    categories
WHERE
    status = 'active'
ORDER BY
    parentid ASC,
    name ASC
```

However, it seems that this is the correct data being brought back so I'll continue on.

The OP would like the array formatted like a heirarchy. For future reference, please see: [PHP/MySQL - building a nav menu hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477793/php-mysql-building-a-nav-menu-hierarchy). The easiest way to do this, would be to follow the OP's original (non MVC) function and add it as a model function. This model function would create a nested array, rather than the direct html output -- the reason for this is to separate application logic from output.

You can add the following to your model as a function. Originally taken from [Nested sets, php array and transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841014/nested-sets-php-array-and-transformation) but since re-written due to errors appearing for OP:

```
function to_hierarchy($collection = NULL)
{
    if (is_null($collection)) return false;

    $tree = array();

    foreach($collection[0] as $key => $value)
    {
        $tree[$value] = array();

        foreach($collection[$key] as $item)
        {
            array_push($tree[$value], $item);
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Now we can update our controller to be the following:

*cat_menu.php (Controller)*

```
<?php

class Cat_menu extends Controller
{

    function Cat_menu()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function make_menu($parent = FALSE) //Is this $parent argument needed?
    {
        $this->load->model('cat_menu_model');

        $get_nav_list = $this->cat_menu_model->get_categories_nav();

        $format_nav_list = $this->cat_menu_model->to_hierarchy($get_nav_list);

        //Load the HTML helper for ul/ol conversion
        $this->load->helper('html');

        $data['navlist'] = $format_nav_list;

        //If you want to parse data to a view you need to state it
        $this->load->view('menu', $data);
    }
}
```

Now we can update our view to be the following:

menu.php (View)

```
<?php
    echo ul($navlist);
?>
```

***Disclaimer:*** None of the above has been tested using PHP as I currently don't have access to the interpreter from this computer. Please make sure you check over any syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested it and the outputs are Array Array  Array. It does not show menu.

Comment: Change your view to simply read:

echo '<pre>'.print_r($navlist).'</pre>';

From this you can see what output is created from your model function, and alter your view (or model?) accordingly.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [7] => clothes [8] => fun ) [7] => Array ( [3] => pants [2] => shirts [1] => shoes ) [8] => Array ( [6] => games [5] => toys ) )

Comment: @scorchin: Thanks again. I tink line $format_nav_list = $this->cat_menu_model->to_hierarchy($navlist); should be $format_nav_list = $this->cat_menu_model->to_hierarchy($get_nav_list);
However I get an error "Message: Undefined index: depth"

Comment: Thanks. I've since ammended the code to be a lot simpler and it should now fit your problem, rather than be a generic nested array builder. Let me know if you have anymore trouble

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Scorchin. I needed to add echo in front of ul in view. Otherwise it works! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Scorchin: Can you explain what is happening in your code here? 'foreach($collection[0] as $key => $value)
       {
    $tree[$value] = array();
   
    foreach($collection[$key] as $item)
    {
     array_push($tree[$value], $item);
    }
       }'

Comment: @shin I've updated the view code above to fit. As for the to_hierarchy() function, it goes through the result array, where parent = 0 and sets the base of the array tree: $tree[$value] = array(); Then for all other elements in the result array, it will try to find the respective parent and it as a child value: array_push($tree[$value], $item); Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated:
function to_hierarchy($collection = NULL)
        {
       if (is_null($collection)) return false;
   
       $tree = array();
   
       foreach($collection[0] as $key => $value)
      
       {
  $tree[$value] = array();
  
   if (isset($collection[$key])){
   
    foreach($collection[$key] as $item)
    {
     array_push($tree[$value], $item);
    
     
    }
   }
       }
 return $tree;
   }

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider looking at the [`ul()` function in the built-in HTML helper](http://codeigniter.com/user%5Fguide/helpers/html_helper.html#ol_and_ul), which lets you create a `<ul>` out of an array, recursively.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this helper does not suit in this situation. But I learnt new thing.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're not passing the data to the view in the controller.
it should be:

$this -> load ->view('menu',$data);

also, it looks like you would cause an infinite loop the way you currently have it set up. make_menu loads the menu.php view, but then the view calls that method.